# Is one allowed to endanger his life for learning Torah like Hillel did?

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, pikuachnefesh-danger-life, masechet-yoma, hillel

The famous story about Hillel's devotion to Torah learning, in [Yoma 25b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.35b?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi), tells that Hillel endangered his life by trying to listen to Shmayah and Avtalyon in extremely cold weather until he fell unconscious.

While educationally exemplary, how Halachicly correct is this behavior? If he asked his teachers for permission would they allow him to do that? And did he subsequently teach others that it is permitted?